# Unable to reload UITableView after connectionDidFinishLoading completes

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2

I am downloading and parsing JSON objects to build a "news feed" to populate a UITableView. The very last line of code I have in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method is:

```
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

However, my break points in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)mytableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method are not hit.  (They are hit when the app first launches)

So for whatever reason even though I am calling the reloadData on the main thread; it doesn't appear to be firing.   I tried just [tableView reloadData] and that did not work.

Here is my connectionDidFinishLoading method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{       

    //NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil]; 

    NSUInteger newsStreamCount = [publicTimeline count];

    // Initialize the collection and the dictionary
    newsItemManager.newsItemCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:newsStreamCount];
    NSMutableArray *dictOfNewsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:newsStreamCount];

    // From the JSON object, parse out the individual news item JSON objects and 
    // put them into a dictionary.
    for (int i = 0; i < newsStreamCount; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *item = [publicTimeline objectAtIndex:i];
        [dictOfNewsItems addObject:item];
    }

    // For each news item JSON object, extract out the information we need for our
    // news manager class
    for (int i = 0; i < newsStreamCount; i++)
    {
        NSString *userName = [[dictOfNewsItems objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Title"];
        NSString *message = [[dictOfNewsItems objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Content"];
        NSString *imgUrl = [[dictOfNewsItems objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"https://si0.twimg.com/logo_normal.jpg"];


        NewsItem *newsItem = [[NewsItem alloc] initWithBasicInfo:userName :message :imgUrl];


        [newsItemManager.newsItemCollection addObject:newsItem];
    }

    [tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* newsItemArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Here is my implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.title = @"News";

    //self.newsItemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

    tableView.rowHeight = 75.0;


    responseData = [NSMutableData data];        
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blah.com/api/news"]];
    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

Thanks,
Flea

Comment: Is tableView nil for some reason at the time you call performSelector on it?   NSLog (@" Tableview is %@", tableView);

Comment: Yes Ray, sure seems like it:  It printed out: Tableview is (null)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the case; I am @synthesize at the top of the class.

Comment: I think the problem has to be because this UITableView pointer is null but I am not sure why that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall problem was my newsItemManager.newsItemCollection was not being initialized properly and was returning null the entire time, thus when the UITableView was trying to load data; there was nothing to load.

I thought I had checked for this but one of those problems of staring at the computer all day and missing the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If your connectionDidFinish... method is inside your tableViewController class, maybe you just need

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Please post your .h file where tableview is declared, as well as your init method (or whereever you initialize tableview).  Does the table EVER show data?

Comment: Hey Ray, I updated my main question and put my header info and implementation info up there.   I was able to get the table to display the contents of a simple array outside of using the connectionDidFinish method.

Comment: Where do you set the tableView's dataSource? It should be newsItemManager.newsItemCollection...